# How to read the "Git Build Data" in Jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins

While investigating this issue:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947454/jenkins-git-plugin-doesnt-work-for-git-flow, I found some interesting information in the build result as shown below. Can anyone explain to me what does this "Git Build Data" try to tell me? Which plugin generated this?

```
Checking out Revision b3a750cf4b36be8528591aa7c3606e83da688ade (origin/development, origin/release)


Git Build Data

Revision: b3a750cf4b36be8528591aa7c3606e83da688ade
origin/development
origin/release
Built Branches

origin/DEVOP-237: Build #54 of Revision 1d3e706e8bce5ac50e125a5bd74a4aa813c0c6e1 (origin/DEVOP-237)
origin/development: Build #57 of Revision b3a750cf4b36be8528591aa7c3606e83da688ade (origin/development, origin/release)
refs/remotes/origin/master: Build #55 of Revision e5cea21924c0365b5c212af16b1f9e4f473ea87e (refs/remotes/origin/master)
origin/release: Build #57 of Revision b3a750cf4b36be8528591aa7c3606e83da688ade (origin/development, origin/release)
```

Comment: Ever figure this out, I now have a similar question.

Answer (score 7):

The Git plugin itself produces the Git Build Data page, accessed from a specific build page. It contains both information for *this* build and for *all previous* builds of this Jenkins build project.

At the top, in the **Revision** section, it shows the SHA1 hash of the commit that the plugin checked out and built. Under each commit, it lists any branches that pointed to that commit when it was built, whether they're local or remote. In this case it built commit `b3a750cf4b36be8528591aa7c3606e83da688ade`, which was the tip of branches `origin/development` and `origin/release` at that time.

The **Built Branches** section lists all the branches that were previously built by this build project, the previous build number that built that branch, the commit for that build, and other references that matched. So, it's telling you that:

`origin/DEVOP-237` was last built before this as build #54. The revision that it pointed to at the time was `1d3e706e`. The only branch that pointed to that revision was `origin/DEVOP-237`.

`origin/development` was last built as build #75. The revision was `b3a750cf` which was pointed to by `origin/development` and `origin/release`.

`refs/remotes/origin/master` (which is an alias for `origin/master`) was last built as build #55. The commit pointed to was `e5cea219` and again it was only pointed to by `refs/remotes/origin/master`.

The `origin/release` data just duplicates the `origin/development` data.

Because the **Built Branches** data appears to be captured for each build, if you want to know the *latest* build for each branch, you need to look first at the most recent build.